# Jquery dialogbox content sometimes returns old data

Tags: javascript, jquery

so on my page i'm having many button each button contains some data and when I click on any button it opens dialog box with 2 input both date type..and if i change something it will save it for that particular button.
The problem is if i click on button A sometimes(very rarely this happen but still i need to find some solution) the dialog opens data for button C.What to do..?

Any suggestion or help appreciated.

Thanks.

Code:

```
            $("#dialog").dialog({

                            height: 450,
                            width: 450,
                            modal: true,
                            title: "Dialog BOx",

                            buttons: {

                                "Save": function () {
                                   start_dt = moment($('#start_txt').val());
                                   end_dt = moment($('#end_txt').val());
                                   _this.SaveData(start_dt,end_dt);
                                   $(this).dialog('close');
                              }
                                close: function () {
                                   $(this).dialog('close');
                            },

                        });
```

---

### HTML:

```
              <div id="dialog" title="" style="width:500px;">
               <input type="date" id="start_txt"/>
               <input type="date" id="end_txt"/>  
                </div>
```

Comment: Try clear the data when dialog closed each time . So when next click, it shows data for the relevant button. How you are loading data for each button? is it using any ajax or fixed somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Dialog Close event](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close) with

```
$("#dialog")
   .dialog({
     closeOnEscape: true,
     show: "slow",
     model: true,
     minWidth: 600,
     close: function( event, ui ) {
           //Do stuff on close
           //Now call "destroy"
          $("#dialog").dialog("destroy");
     }
  });
```

Comment: I have already tried                                                                  $("#dialog").empty() ,$("#dialog").remove() ,$("#start_txt").val(''),$("#start_txt").val(null)

Comment: it rarely happen so right now i can't say if it's working or not but i have included your suggestion.Thanks. I'll wait for today if everything goes right I'll tell you..

Comment: You can check this as well if it doesn't works for you https://forum.jquery.com/topic/removing-content-in-ui-dialog-after-close